# Do [spoilers] leave a corpse when they die?

Tags: betrayal-legacy

Since the quetion is about a mechanic revealed in Chapter 3, I'll leave most of it in the spoilers.

> We recently added Inhabitants to our game. The rules say that when they die, we "turn over the token representing them." Does this turned over token count as a *corpse* for items that would care about corpses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Inhabitants will not create a corpse.

The term "corpse" is mentioned one time in the rulebook (not counting an example haunt), in the Dying section. This refers specifically to *one of your traits* moving to the skull, which kills the character and creates a corpse.

> **DYING**
>
> Once the haunt begins, **if any of your traits moves to the skull, then
>   you die**. Tip over your figure on your tile. DROP all your Items,
>   Omens, and Objects. **You are now a corpse**.
>
> Even if the traitor dies, as long as the monsters can complete the
>   haunt’s goals, the monsters still get their turn (under the traitor’s
>   control) and the traitor can still win.

From the [Rulebook PDF](https://media.wizards.com/2018/downloads/rules/BLY-Rulebook-web.pdf)

> *Your traits* refers to the traits of a player's character.

Answer (score -1):

As the rules concerning dying are explained before the inclusion of Inhabitants, the rules on their deaths may be open to debate. Inhabitants do leave a ghost in the event of their death, and as the Inhabitant tokens do have a side that marks whether the inhabitants are alive or dead and that Inhabitants do not return to following games in the campaign, I believe it’s fair to say that inhabitants do leave a corpse when killed.